# How can i use * in css to select all but only one

Tags: html, css

I want to make that class to do it job for all the tags but only for the mentionned element

How can i use this class

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

without select this element ?

```css
<div id="top_header_nav">
     <div id="top_header_top" class="top_header_tabs"></div>
     <div id="top_header_networks" class="top_header_tabs"><a href="https://www.site.nl">Networks</a></div>
     <div id="top_header_systems" class="top_header_tabs"><a href="https://www.site.nl">Systems</a></div>
      <div id="top_header_xs" class="top_header_tabs"><a href="https://www.site.nl">XS</a></div>
      <div id="top_header_prints" class="top_header_tabs"><a href="https://www.site.nl">Prints</a></div>
          
      <div id="top_header_extra">
              <a class="knop" href="https://cp.site.com">Controle Paneel</a><a class="knop" href="https://www.siet.nl/securewebmail"> Webmail</a><br>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top_header_nav{
box-sizing: some other value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, i don't to use `box-sizing` at all

Comment: then just set box-sizing to default or whatever value

Comment: @JDEV the default value is `content-box`. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Glad it has helped @JDEV